# how to dismiss one of the modal, when triggered two modal in the bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have two modal in my form, what I am trying to do is, when I create a pop-up modal for the user to create the campaign when I create the campaign, I want to make pop-up another modal to let them confirm again. However, when I triggered the cancel button on the confirm modal there, it will auto dismiss all of the modal.

The following is my yes no modal.

```
<div class="modal fade stick-up CampaignYesNoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CampaignYesNoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

        <div class="modal-content text-center">
            <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <i class="pg-close fs-14 "></i>
                </button>
                <h5 id="messageBox2" class="text-center" style="font-size:14px">Create Campaign?</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center !important">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="modalYesBtn2" name="modalYesBtn2" style="width:80px">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal" style="width:80px">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I cancel it will cancel boot of the modal, how to prevent it to happen?

Comment: How you are cancelling it ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay u see the source code got cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to reconfigure `data-dismiss` buttons.

I have configured proceed button to go ahead and close both modals and cancel button to close only the confirmation modal.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Begin Your Campaign</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Campaign Manager</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some input to take data here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CampaignYesNoModal">Proceed</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade stick-up CampaignYesNoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CampaignYesNoModal" id="CampaignYesNoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content text-center">
            <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <i class="pg-close fs-14 "></i>
                </button>
                <h5 id="messageBox2" class="text-center" style="font-size:14px">Create Campaign?</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center !important">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:80px">Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added `data-toggle` attribute to the proceed, so it closes (toggle) the first modal while `data-dismiss` closes the second modal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is a way to do this:

First, change close tag like mentioned below for both of the modal(s):

```
<button type="button" class="close">    // Notice that I have removed `data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" so it will not close any modal`
    <i class="pg-close fs-14 "></i>
</button>
```

Then, write jquery code to close the respective modal only,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').parents('.modal:first').hide();
});
```

Above mentioned code will close the relevant modal only.